# Python 2D Matrix Interpolation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix with some Float-values and a lot of NaN values. Now I want to interpolate the NaN-values.

The matrix looks like:

```
[
  [NaN, NaN, 3.9, NaN, NaN],
  [3.2, NaN, NaN, 2.9, NaN],
  [NaN, NaN, 2.5, NaN, NaN],
  [7.6, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.3],
  [NaN, 0.6, NaN, NaN, NaN]
]
```

I know that there exists **scipy.interpolate.interp2d** (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html). But I want to do a Spline-Interpolation. With **pandas** (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) I can do spline, but I am not sure if it and how it works for 2 dimensional Data. Maybe there is someone, who could help me! :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Year, maybe you need this is pandas solution:

```
a = [
  [None, None, 3.9, None, None],
  [3.2, None, None, 2.9, None],
  [None, None, 2.5, None, None],
  [7.6, None, None, None, 1.3],
  [None, 0.6, None, None, None]
]
b = {i:a[i] for i in range(len(a))}
c = pd.DataFrame(b).T
c.interpolate(limit_direction ='both',inplace=True,axis=0)
```

If you need interpolation fill row-by-row then switch `axis=1`